# How to detect cycling edges that point to one of the upper nodes?

Tags: javascript, graph

I have a list of edges and I want to filter out the cyclic ones.

Take a look at this screenshot:

[image]

In this case I would like to detect that the red edge is cyclic, because it points to the upper node

In the code, all I have is a notion of edges, that look like this:

```
const edges = [
  { id: "1", source: "1", target: "2" },
  { id: "2", source: "1", target: "3" },
  { id: "3", source: "2", target: "4" },
  { id: "4", source: "4", target: "5" },
  { id: "5", source: "5", target: "3" }
];
```

How to detect if an edge is cyclic?

My idea:
Given the fact that the Node 1 always exists and is a starting point then I could calculate on what "levels" each node is. In the above case, the Node 5 is on level 4 and Node 3 is on level 2. Then compare the levels.

Is there some JavaScript library helper package that handles this kind of things?

Comment: You should use a inversed tree to create a [union find data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure). [Kurskal's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_algorithm) also uses such a data structure to dectect cycles in a graph.

Comment: The list of edges doesn't match the image; node 1 has two targets for instance. Anyway, you can iterate over all nodes and use recursion to keep going to the next target and check it against the first node. As soon as it matches, you've found a cycle. Which edge is causing the loop is a separate and to me impossible question because any edge that is part of a loop can be regarded as causing it

Comment: @ChrisG I think it matches, you can see the first two items in an array have source "1", and the targets are "2" and "3" which is what is on the image, right?

Comment: You're right, it's a list of edges not nodes. Sorry, I'll post code soon. edit: wait, there's no edge leading away from node3 so it's not cyclic

Comment: @ChrisG oh you are right, I think I misunderstood cyclic vs this scenario. I think for my case this should be what i'm looking for: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/level-node-tree-source-node-using-bfs/

Comment: Here's code that works if the edges are cyclic: https://jsbin.com/vetokenumi/edit?js,console

Comment: @ChrisG thanks that's really helpful. In case of the above, do you know how to determine the level of the nodes starting from a root node? Node 1 in this case, I'm struggling to implement that

Answer (score 0):

### How to determine the level of the nodes?

```js
const edges = [{
    id: "1",
    source: "1",
    target: "2"
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    source: "1",
    target: "3"
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    source: "2",
    target: "4"
  },
  {
    id: "4",
    source: "4",
    target: "5"
  },
  {
    id: "5",
    source: "5",
    target: "3"
  }
]

edges.forEach(edge => {
  console.log(getLevel(edge))
})

function getLevel(node) {
  let current = node
  let level = 0
  while (true) {
    const parent = edges.find(edge => edge.target === current.source)
    if (!parent) return level
    current = parent
    level += 1
  }
}
```

### How to detect cycling edges that point to one of the upper nodes?

```js
const edges = [{
    id: "1",
    source: "1",
    target: "2"
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    source: "1",
    target: "3"
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    source: "2",
    target: "4"
  },
  {
    id: "4",
    source: "4",
    target: "5"
  },
  {
    id: "5",
    source: "5",
    target: "3"
  }
]

console.log(findCyclingNode())

function findCyclingNode() {
  const visited = []
  for (const edge of edges) {
    if (visited.includes(edge.target)) return edge.target
    visited.push(edge.target)
  }
}
```